# Associate different models in the same relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to associate different models in the same relation, like this;
A `User` can have many different friends, but each friends model are different both with respect to validation and data.

```
User.first.friends # => [BestFriend, RegularFriend, CloseFriend, ...]
```

Each friend class has different columns but they all respond to the same method `#to_s`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friends # What more to write here?
end

class BestFriend < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :shared_interests # Shared between all friend models
  validates_presence_of :favourite_colour # Does only exists in this model

  def to_s
    "This is my best friend whos favourite colour is #{favourite_colour} ..."
  end
end

class RegularFriend < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :shared_interests # Shared between all friend models
  validates_presence_of :address # Does only exists in this model

  def to_s
    "This is a regular friend who lives at #{address} ..."
  end
end

class CloseFriend < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :shared_interests # Shared between all friend models
  validates_presence_of :car_type # Does only exists in this model

  def to_s
    "This is a close friend who drives a #{car_type} ..."
  end
end
```

This is want I'm trying to achieve.

1. It should be possible to paginate and eager load friends on user `user.friends.page(4).per(10)`.
2. A friend must contain a `user_id` to ensure that the record is unique. The attributes on a friend without `user_id` can't be unique as the values might be shared between friends.
3. Each friend has its own validation and columns, which means that they need their own class.

Here is an example of how this could be used.

```
user = User.create!

CloseFriend.create!({ car_type: "Volvo", shared_interests: "Diving", user: user })
RegularFriend.create!({ country: "Norway", shared_interests: "Swim", user: user })
BestFriend.create!({ favourite_colour: "Blue", shared_interests: "Driving", user: user })
BestFriend.create({ shared_interests: "Driving", user: user }) # => Invalid record

user.friends.page(1).per(3).order("created_at ASC").each do |friend|
  puts friend.to_s
  # This is a close friend who drives a Volvo ...
  # This is a regular friend who lives in Norway ...
  # This is my best friend whos favourite colour is Blue ...
end
```

How would it be possible to solve this?

Comment: Two techniques: STI and polymorphic. Too long to explain here and tons of explanation are easy to find. Start here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: @BenjaminSinclaire STI and a polymorphic association wont work out of the box in my case (unless you know something i don't). The friends table (`close_friends` for example) has to have at least one foreign key to validate its uniqueness. Using just `belongs_to ..., polymorphic: true` on `User` will only allow a foreign key for the `Friend`, `User` relation on `User`.

Comment: I agree with @BenjaminSinclaire. Not sure why STI won't work. Can you explain that further?

Comment: @Oleander - How many friends do a user have in this system? Is the data updated often?  Depending on these you can choose to either denomalize the friend's ids or create database view

Comment: I've provided a comprehensive answer which addresses your question and you have downvoted despite it being taken from a real application, not using polymorphic joins, using separate classes for validation and to_s functionality, not requiring separate queries and supporting chaining and pagination (I go to great pains to explain where you will have trouble with AR down the road). Your behavior reflects a level ignorance and is insulting to all those who have taken time to provide legitimate answers. I've had this question flagged for moderation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using combination of store_accessor and STI. The store accessors will allow you to add model specific attributes with support for validation. If you use PostgreSQL you can take advantage of GIN/GiST index to search custom fields efficiently.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friends
end

class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base      
  belongs_to :user

  # exclude nil values from uniq check 
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, allow_nil: true


  # The friends table should have a text column called  
  # custom_attrs. 
  # In Postgres you can use hstore data type. Then
  # next line is not required.
  store      :custom_attrs

  # Shared between all friend models
  store_accessor [ :shared_interests ]
  validates_presence_of :shared_interests

  # bit of meta-programming magic to add helper
  # associations in User model.
  def self.inherited(child_class)
    klass = child_class.name 
    name = klass.pluralize.underscore.to_sym
    User.has_many name, -> {where(type: klass)}, class_name:  klass
  end
end
```

Define various friend models with model specific attributes.

```
class BestFriend < Friend
  store_accessor [ :favourite_colour ]
  validates_presence_of :favourite_colour

  def to_s
    "This is my best friend whos favourite colour is #{favourite_colour} ..."
  end
end

class RegularFriend  < Friend
  store_accessor [ :address ]
  validates_presence_of :address

  def to_s
    "This is a regular friend who lives at #{address} ..."
  end
end

class CloseFriend <  Friend
  store_accessor [ :car_type ]
  validates_presence_of :car_type

  def to_s
    "This is a close friend who drives a #{car_type} ..."
  end
end
```

**Usage**

```
user = User.create!

user.close_friends.create!(
  car_type: "Volvo", 
  shared_interests: "Diving"
)

user.regular_friends.create!(
  country: "Norway", 
  shared_interests: "Diving"
)

user.best_friends.create!(
  favourite_colour: "Blue", 
  shared_interests: "Diving"
)

# throws error
user.best_friends.create!(
  shared_interests: "Diving"
)

# returns all friends
user.friends.page(4).per(10)
```

**Reference**

[Store documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html)

[PostgreSQL Hstore documentation:](http://mikecoutermarsh.com/using-hstore-with-rails-4/)

Comment: +1 This is almost exactly what I've been experimenting the last couple of days. The only difference is that I used [flex_columns](https://github.com/ageweke/flex_columns) to store my data.

Comment: @Oleander, `store` feature is built in to rails. On Postgres database, `store_accessor` along with `hstore` data type enables you to implement NoSQL on RDBMS.

Comment: There is no reason to use hstore for this. You cannot ensure referential integrity if your attributes link to other information in related tables, everything is a string, you cant use database level check constraints. Generally I only resort or hstore/JSON/JSONB when I don't know all the attributes upfront. Since the question is very concerned with validations on specific attributes in specific types of friends this answer is not aligned with those goals.

Comment: Fogot to add that whilst these are great features and postgres has excellent indexing support they are still not as fast as a regular column for read and GIst/gin indexes are much larger indexes and much slower on create/update.

Comment: @AndrewHacking, OP was interested in uniqueness verification, which is achieved by the `belongs_to` association suggested in my answer. From user's problem description, I gather that he is trying to store extended attributes in individual models. If you see OP's comment, he was about to use https://github.com/ageweke/flex_columns. My answer suggests a native solution for such an use case.

Comment: @HarishShetty The original question makes no mention of flex columns or a desire for a schemaless design and in fact is rather specific in wanting separate classes and known attributes with known validation rules. A schemaless approach is completely unnecessary here and not a good design, whilst postgres hstore, jsonb are good when the data isn't known they do have larger index size overhead, are slower than native, much slower to create or update rows, but most importantly database integrity is significantly compromised (a concern implied with the validation requirement).

Answer (score 5):

I like this question. My answer will be long :)

First of all you expirience problems because your Ruby OOP architecture conflicts with relational database principles. Just think about tables where you store your data. Normally you cannot store data in different tables and fetch it with one query. Because SQL responds you with records of the same type but tables' rows have different types.

Let's look from the other side. You have User model. You have several ?Friend models and they all friends actually. So even if they don't share behaviour you must inherit them from one base class (called Friend I guess) because you want use them in pagination as objects with the same behaviour (it is not required by ruby but is required by classic OOP design). Now you have something like that in RoR:

```
class User < AR::Base
  has_many :friends
end

class Friend < AR::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class BestFriend < Friend
end

class OldFriend < Friend
end
```

Luckly you are not the first :) There are some patterns that projects OOP inheritance on RDBMS. They described by Martin Fowler in his Pattetns of Enterprise Application Architecture (aka PoEAA).

1. First is mentioned here [STI](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html) (Single Table Inheritance). It is preferred way because Rails already has built-in STI support. Also STI lets you fetch all data with one DB-request because it is one-table query. BUT STI has some drawbacks. Main is that you must store all your data in one table. This means that all your models will share fields of one table. For example your BestFriend model has `alias` attribute and OldFriend does not but anyway ActiveRecord will create `alias` and `alias=` methods for you. It is not clean from OOP point of view. All that you can do is undefine these methods or override them with `raise 'Not Available for %s' % self.class.name`.
2. Second is [Concrete Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html). It is not so appropiate for you because you won't have one table with all records and won't able to do simple query for pagination (actually you do but only with some weird DB stuff). But indisputable advantage of Concrete Table Inheritance is that all your friend models will have independent fields. It is clean from OOP prospective.
3. Third is [Class Table inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html). It is not compatible with ActiveRecord pattern without using database views and instead of triggers but is too complex for your problem. Class Table inheritance is compatible with DataMapper pattern but Rails heavily depends on ActiveRecord.

You can easily achieve your goal with NoSQL solutions. You just create collection of friends in something like MongoDB and just store all data in the collection's documents. But don't use Mongo :)

So I recommend you to use STI but I have some nice trick. If you use PostgreSQL you can store all your model-specific data in JSON or hstore column and combine flexibility of NoSQL with RDBMS schema strictness and ActiveRecord power. Just create setters/getters for your model-specific columns. Like this:

```
class Friend < AR::Base
  def self.json_accessor(*names)
    names.each do |name|
      class_eval(<<-RUBY, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1)
        def #{name}
          friend_details['#{name}']
        end

        def #{name}=(value)
          # mark attribute as dirty
          friend_details_will_change!
          friend_details['#{name}'] = value
        end
      RUBY
    end
  end
end

class BestFriend < Friend
  json_accessor :alias
end
```

This is not the only way but I hope all this stuff will help you to create a solid solution.

P.S. Sorry. I think it's almost blogpost not just answer. But I'm very passionate about all these DB-related things :)

P.P.S. Sorry once again. Just can't stop. Bonus for Concrete Table Inheritance. You are still able to create all-in-one table with separate tables using database views. Example:

DB:

```
CREATE VIEW FRIENDS
AS
SELECT ID,
       USER_ID,
       NAME,
       'best' TYPE
FROM   BEST_FRIENDS
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,
       USER_ID,
       NAME,
       'old' TYPE
FROM   OLD_FRIENDS
UNION ALL
...
```

Rails:

```
class User < AR::Base
  has_many :friends
end

class Friend < AR::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def to_concrete
    ('%sFriend' % type.camelize).find(id)
  end
end

class BestFriend < Friend
end

class OldFriend < Friend
end
```

Usage:

```
user = User.create!
BestFriend.create!(user_id: user.id, alias: 'Foo', name: 'Bar')
OldFriend.create!(user_id: user.id, name: 'Baz')

user.friends
# One SQL query to FRIENDS view
# [#Friend(id: 1, type: 'best', name: 'Bar'), #Friend(id: 2, type: 'old', name: 'Baz')]
user.friends.map(&:name) 
# ['Bar', 'Baz']
user.first.alias
# NoMethodError
user.first.to_concrete
# #BestFriend(id: 1, name: 'Bar', alias: 'Foo')
user.first.to_concrete.alias
# 'Foo'
user.second.to_concrete
# #OldFriend(id: 2, name: 'Baz')
user.second.to_concrete.alias
# NoMethodError
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but as a thought, you could try creating multiple models using the same table, each with a different default scope.

```
def BestFriend < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name "friends"
  default_scope -> { where(friendship: 'best') }
end

def RegularFriend < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name "friends"
  default_scope -> { where(friendship: 'regular') }
end
```

you still have `has_many :friends` in the User class, hopefully when the records are read the scope would match the table record to the appropriate model.

EDIT

Since the only thing you need to respond to for all records is :to_s you could have a generic Friend class just for use with the relation.

```
class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_s
    case friendship
    when 'best'
      object = BestFriend.find(self.id)
    when 'regular'
     object = RegularFriend.find(self.id)
    end
    object.to_s
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think that will work. The user class will still load data into the `Friend` class, which doesn't exist. The user class has to look at the (in your case) `friendship` column and pass the data to that class after loading the content from the db.

Comment: Let me try it out... hang on.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. :( uninitialized constant User::Friend ... I don't believe we can get after_find callback to return a replacement record. But does it matter if you have a Friend class?  Since the only thing you need to respond to for all records is :to_s you could have a User class with...  def to_s; case friendship; when 'best'; object = BestFriend.find(self.id);when 'regular';object = RegularFriend.find(self.id);end;object.to_s; end

Comment: It's hard to read my comment... I've modified the answer to make it clearer!

Comment: Although I appreciate that's an extra IO ... :(

Comment: Aha. That sounds like a good idea. I'll write some specs later tonight to see if it works.

Comment: I'll give you the 100 reps for pointing me in the right direction which helped to solve the problem. The answer doesn't solve my problem completely tho so I can't mark it as correct. Take a look at @Harish Shetty answer for a complete solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

**Single Table Inheritance**

You'll likely be best using an [`STI`](http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance), as per the comments

The issue you have is you're referencing the same data-set in different variations. "Best", "Close" & "Regular" are all types of *friend* - meaning it will be much better (and in keeping with the [Single Source of Truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Source_of_Truth) principle) to store them in a single table / model

You could do this:

```
#app/models/user/close.rb
Class User::Close < Friend
   ...
end

#app/models/user/best.rb
Class User::Best < Friend
   ...
end

#app/models/user/regular.rb
Class User::Regular < Friend
   ...
end
```

This will allow you to associate your `User` model to the different types of friends like this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :bffs, class: "User::Best"
    has_many :regs, class: "User::Regular"
    has_many :closies, class: "User::Close"
end
```

Not as DRY as you may hope - but allows you to use a single data table to store the relative files you need

--

**Conditional**

An alternative is to use a conditional association:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :friends, ->(type="regular") { where(type: type) }
end
```

This would allow you to call:

```
@user = User.find params[:id]
@user.friends("best")
```

Comment: As I explained above regarding the first answer; the problem is that I have `n` friend classes. In your first example this will force me to add n has_many rows and and do n requests to fetch all data (pagination wont be possible) , which isn't relastistic. The second example wont work eather as I need `n` different classes, not just one friend class.

Comment: Who says you need `n` different classes? what's the reason?

Comment: Each friend model requires its own validations has they've different columns. That's why you solution requires `n` rows, one for each friend class.

Answer (score -1):

I've done this using STI (Single Table Inheritence) but where things fall down with ActiveRecord is that you have limited ability to express join conditions and can't do things like union all when it comes to searching related information even when you know exactly the sql you want.

Eg find all friends and friends of friends who posted in the last x days with 'foo' in the title or trending. Simple org/person relationships can't be searched when the related information is not carried in the table. Sure AR/Arel  will generate queries but not the one you want no matter what you do.

And you can't use SQL strings to join as you get an array and not a relation back which means chaining doesn't work.

I moved to Sequel where I can actually compose my queries and access useful sql features  moving beyond simple crud patterns which about what AR is good for.

Heres an AR example (with the above caveat that AR has severe limitations compared to sequel) which defines Party (People, Organisations, Users and subtypes thereof - uses STI) and rich relationships between them (BestFriend etc) which hold attributes of the relationship (Relationship also uses STI).

There are no polymorphic joins since the base tables are fixed.

First the Party model:

```
class Party < ActiveRecord::Base

  ###################################################
  # relationships

  has_many :left_relationships,
    class_name: 'Relationship',
    foreign_key: :left_party_id,
    inverse_of: :left_party

  has_many :right_parties,
    through: :left_relationships,
    source: :right_party

  has_many :right_relationships,
    class_name: 'Relationship',
    foreign_key: :right_party_id,
    inverse_of: :right_party

  has_many :left_parties,
    through: :right_relationships,
    source: :left_party

  def relationships
    Relationship.involving_party(self)
  end

  def peers
    left_parties.merge(right_parties).uniq
  end
end
```

Now the Relationship model, this has some useful scopes for finding relationships pertaining to any party, a community of parties, or between groups of parties:

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :save_parties
  belongs_to :left_party,
    class_name: 'Party',
    inverse_of: :left_relationships
  belongs_to :right_party,
    class_name: 'Party',
    inverse_of: :right_relationships

  # scopes
  #

  # relationships for the given party/parties
  def self.involving_party(party)
    any_of({left_party_id: party}, {right_party_id: party})
  end

  # all relationships between left and right parties/groups
  def self.between_left_and_right(left_group, right_group)
    where(left_party_id: left_group, right_party_id: right_group)
  end

protected
  def save_parties
    left_party.save if left_party
    right_party.save if right_party
  end
end
```

Some required and very useful AR extensions:

```
module ARExtensions
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    module ClassMethods
      # return a relation/scope that matches any of the provided
      # queries. This is basically OR on steroids.
      def any_of(*queries)
        where(
          queries.map do |query|
            query = where(query) if [String, Hash].any? { |type| query.kind_of? type }
            query = where(*query) if query.kind_of? Array
            query.arel.constraints.reduce(:and)
          end.reduce(:or)
        )
      end

      # polyfil for AR scope removal which has no equivalent
      def scoped(options=nil)
        options ? where(nil).apply_finder_options(options, true) : where(nil)
      end
    end
end
```

Now the `Person` model, you can call it `User` if you wish but semantics are important to me, you may have people that are not users and may choose to separate the concept of a system user from the concept of a person/party:

```
class Person < Party

  # BestFriend relationships
  has_many :best_friend_relationships,
    class_name: 'BestFriend',
    foreign_key: :right_party_id,
    inverse_of: :left

  has_many :best_friends,
    class_name: 'Person',
    through: :best_friend_relationships,
    source: :best_friend

  has_many :best_friend_of_relationships,
    class_name: 'BestFriend',
    foreign_key: :left_party_id,
    inverse_of: :right

  has_many :best_friends_of,
    class_name: 'Person',
    through: :client_relationships,
    source: :client

  # etc for whatever additional relationship types you have
end
```

The BestFriend relationship:

```
class BestFriend < Relationship
  belongs_to :best_friend_of,
    class_name: 'Person',
    foreign_key: :left_party_id,
    inverse_of: :best_friend_relationships,
    autosave: true

  belongs_to :best_friend,
    class_name: 'Person',
    foreign_key: :right_party_id,
    inverse_of: :best_friend_of_relationships,
    autosave: true

  validates_existence_of :best_friend_of
  validates_existence_of :best_friend, allow_new: true

protected
  def save_parties
    best_friend_of.save if best_friend_of
    self.left_party = best_friend_of
    best_friend.save if best_friend
    self.right_party = best_friend
  end
end
```

Migration (uses the [SchemaPlus](https://github.com/lomba/schema_plus) extension)

```
class CreateParties < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change

    create_table :parties do |t|
      t.timestamps
      t.string :type, index: true
      t.string :name, index: true

      # Person attributes
      t.date :date_of_birth, index: true
      t.integer :gender

      # and so on as required for your different types of parties
    end

    create_table :relationships do |t|
      t.timestamps
      t.string :type, index: true
      t.belongs_to :left_party, index: true, references: :parties, on_delete: :cascade
      t.belongs_to :right_party, index: true, references: :parties, on_delete: :cascade
      t.date :began, index: true
      t.date :ended, index: true

      # attributes for best friends

      # attributes for family members

      # attributes for enemies

    end
  end
end
```

Comment: -1 Sorry, but this doesn't solve any of my problems.

Comment: It is intended to solve the problems you probably don't know about yet. I've been through what you are doing, had everything working with rich relationships and then found AR unable to query the tables efficiently because of deficiencies. The way AR does its joins will cause you no end of pain. Best of luck.

Comment: @Oleander  I've updated to include AR models and migrations from a working application, please remove the down vote.

Answer (score -3):

You can't really do this with Single Table Inheritance and polymorphic associations... those techniques are for a specific class record that can belong to a record for one of several different classes.

What you're doing is pretty much the opposite... records in many different classes can belong to a record in a  common class.

I think you'll need to specify the has_many relationships individually, but make an instance method "friends" that returns the sum of the arrays.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :best_friends
  has_many :regular_friends
  has_many :close_friends
  def friends
    best_friends + regular_friends + close_friends
  end
end
```

If you want to try to generalize this (I haven't tested this) you could try...

```
class User < ActveRecord::Base
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each { |t| has_many t.to_sym if t.ends_with?("_friends") }

  def friends
    friends = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.inject("[]") {  |all, t| all << self.send(t) if t.ends_with?("_friends"); all }
    friends
  end
end
```

Comment: The problem is that I have `n` friend classes. In your example this will force me to add `n` `has_many` rows and and do `n` requests, which isn't relastistic.

Comment: Ok, i've edited the answer to include a generalized method, but I haven't tested it.  Someone may have better suggestions.

Comment: That would require `n` requests to the database. Sorry.

Comment: Well, yes, you've got `n` tables you want to query.  I'm still inclined to think that your best solution is a single table with a type attribute... which you can use to condition validation.  Good luck!

Comment: I was hoping to avoid conditional validations using one single class. It would be better if it was possible to use one table (as you said) and separate the logic into different classes.